# What is the difference between [.]* and '.*' for command 'find -name'?

Tags: linux, bash, find

My goal is to find all files or directories in a filesystem that start with a dot (`.`), for example `.gnupg`. So I came up with the command:

```
find -name '.*'
```

Checking on the Internet, I saw some hints saying that I should use `[.]*` instead as the parameter value for `-name` option. What is the difference between both approach, since the result looks like the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference at all. If you try:

```
$ diff <(find -name '.*') <(find -name '[.]*')
```

you get no output. This means that command outputs are identical. I think you're taking that "hint" out of context. The intent was probably something different.

From the `find` man page:

> -name pattern
>   Base of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading  directories
>   removed)  matches  shell  pattern  pattern.   The metacharacters
>   (`*',`?', and `[]') match a`.' at the start of the  base  name
>   (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2)

meaning that `[]` in the `-name` argument is construed as a character class. With nothing but `.` in it, it matches a literal `.` as if you didn't use the `[]`.

Comment: The command you show is not proving anything

Comment: @Bernhard Please elaborate.

Comment: One example can not be used as a proof. Only a counter-example can be used to disproof something.

Comment: @Bernhard Fair enough. Does the edit help?

Answer (score 0):

For a glob pattern, there is no difference. `.*` is a literal period followed by zero or more characters. `[.]*` is any one character inside the brackets--in this case, it has to be a literal period--followed by zero or more characters.

The similar looking *regular expressions* `.*` and `[.]*` are different. The first is zero or more occurrences of any single character, while the second is zero or more occurrences of a literal period. The `.` is a regular expression metacharacter, but not inside square brackets, where it is treated literally.

Comment: Except that, when using `-name`, `.` (outside a character class) is also a literal character not a regex metacharacter.

Comment: Yes. Based on the original question, it looked like the OP was reading advice meant for regular expressions, which is why I brought them up.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
'\.[a-z]*'
```

The expression expects a literal dot followed by any amount of alphabetic characters. It seemed to work for me in a quick test.
You need the backslash to escapes the dot. It's usually a meta-character signifying "any character" (more or less).

My whole expression was

```
find ~/ -name '\.[a-z]*'
```

Edit: To include dot-files starting with numbers too, try `'\.[a-z0-9]*'`. I'm not quite sure why you can't just say `'\.(.*)'`, but I'm sure someone has a suggestion.

Comment: All "."s are literal in a find pattern. It's not a meta-character unless you use `-regex` instead of `-name`.

Comment: You're confusing the shell wildcard pattern syntax also used by `find -name` with the regex syntax of `grep`, `sed`, etc., also used by `find -regex`.